# Resteasy Exception; Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class ResteasyBootstrap

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy, jboss6.x

I'm getting this error when I try to get this rest service:

> JBWEB000287: **Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap**: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY001745: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher

I'm using Jboss 6.4, I can't see what produce this error, it seems everything is normal. Any idea?

Service Rest:

```
@Path("/message")
public class MessageService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response getMessage(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        String message = "Hello " + ((name != null) && (name.length() > 0) ? name : "anonymous");

        return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();
    }
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>JAX-RS Example</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.wordpress.infow</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>jaxrs</name>
<url>http://www.infow.wordpress.com</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Trace of the error:

```
17:40:42,459 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TestRestFull]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY001745: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:105) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:82) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:71) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:378) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:233) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the scope of your resteasy dependencies to provided. resteasy is already bundled with JBoss, so the problem might be caused by clash of versions or something similar.

Comment: Thank you @mendieta you reminded me of a super soccer star, Gaizka Mendieta :))